# JPA con estrategia de herencia joined y Spring me salen muchos datos al consultar por id

Tags: spring-boot, spring, jpa

> Hola soy nuevo en JPA estoy haciendo mis primeros pasos con una aplicación , tengo mis tablas como se ven abajo, que es mysql.

```
     CREATE TABLE `persona` (
      `id` int(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `genero` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `edad` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `identificacion` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `direccion` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `telefono` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cliente`;

     CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
      `IdCliente` int(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `contrasena` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `estado` boolean default true,
      `IdPersona` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`idCliente`),
       FOREIGN KEY (IdPersona)
          REFERENCES persona(id) on delete cascade
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=519 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cuenta`;

     CREATE TABLE `cuenta` (
     `NumeroCuenta` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `tipocuenta` varchar(45)  NULL,
     `saldoinicial` decimal(10,2) NULL,
     `estado` boolean default true,
     `id_cliente` int(10) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`NumeroCuenta`),
     FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente)
      REFERENCES cliente(IdCliente) on delete cascade
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Y en mi aplicacion de Spring Boot tengo mis entities
Persona

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="persona")
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class Persona implements Persistable<Long>{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private long id;
    
        @Column(name="nombre")
        private String nombre;
    
        @Column(name="genero")
        private String genero;
    
        @Column(name="edad")
        private int edad;
    
        @Column(name="identificacion")
        private String identificacion;
    
        @Column(name="direccion")
        private String direccion;
    
        @Column(name="telefono")
        private String telefono;
     ...getters and setters
```

> El Entity Cliente

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name="cliente")
     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IdPersona",referencedColumnName = "id")

     @Data
     @NoArgsConstructor
     @AllArgsConstructor
     public class Cliente extends Persona implements Serializable{
    
     // @Id
     // @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
         @Column(name="IdCliente")
         private int idcliente;
    
         @Column(name="contrasena")
         private String pass;
    
         @Column(name="estado",columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
         private Boolean estado;
    
         //@JsonIgnore
         @Column(name="IdPersona",insertable = false,updatable = false)
         private int idpersona;
    
         // @OneToOne
         // @JsonManagedReference
         // @JoinColumn(name="IdPersona")
         // private Persona person;
    
         @JsonManagedReference
         // @OneToMany(mappedBy="idCliente",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
         @OneToMany(mappedBy="idCliente",cascade = 
         CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
         private Set<Cuenta> cuenta=new HashSet<>();
    
         public void addCuenta(Cuenta c){
            cuenta.add(c);
        
         }
         public void removeCuenta(Cuenta c){
              cuenta.remove(c);
        
         }
    
         @PrePersist
         void prePersist() {
            if (this.estado == false || this.estado==null)
               this.estado = true;
         }
    
         public Cliente(String nombre,String genero,int edad,String identificacion,
                String direccion,String telefono,String pass) {
        
               super(nombre,genero,edad,identificacion,direccion,telefono);
               this.pass = pass;
               //this.idpersona = idpersona;
        }

        public Cliente() {
            super();
        }

        public Cliente(int idpersona,String nombre,String telefono,String pass,String 
    direccion, boolean estado) {
            super(nombre,"",0,"",direccion,telefono);
            this.pass = pass;
            this.estado = estado;
            //this.idpersona=idpersona;
        }

        public int getIdcliente() {
            return idcliente;
        }

        public void setIdcliente(int idcliente) {
            this.idcliente = idcliente;
        }

        public String getPass() {
            return pass;
        }

        public void setPass(String pass) {
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        public boolean isEstado() {
            return estado;
        }

        public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
            this.estado = estado;
        }

    //  public int getIdpersona() {
    //      return idpersona;
    //  }
    //
    //  public void setIdpersona(int idpersona) {
    //      this.idpersona = idpersona;
    //  }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cliente [idcliente=" + idcliente + ", pass=" + pass + ", estado=" + 
    estado 
                    + "]";
        }

        public Set<Cuenta> getCuentas() {
            return cuenta;
        }

        public void setCuentas(Set<Cuenta> cuentas) {
            this.cuenta = cuentas;
        }
    ...
```

> El entity de Cuenta

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="cuenta")

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Cuenta implements Serializable{
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="NumeroCuenta")
        private int numerocuenta;
    
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name="tipocuenta")
        private TipoCuenta tipocuenta;
    
        @Column(name="saldoinicial")
        private double saldoinicial;
    
        @Column(name="estado",columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
        private boolean statuscuenta;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="id_cliente",nullable = false,referencedColumnName = "idcliente")
        //  @JsonManagedReference
        @JsonBackReference
        @JsonIgnore
        Cliente idCliente;
    

    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
             return getClass().hashCode();
        }
    
        public Cuenta(TipoCuenta tipocuenta, double saldoinicial, boolean estadocuenta) {
            this.tipocuenta = tipocuenta;
            this.saldoinicial = saldoinicial;
            this.statuscuenta = estadocuenta;
        }

        public Cuenta() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    
    ....getters and setters
```

> Y la clase enum TiooCuenta

```
public enum TipoCuenta {
   AHORRO,CORRIENTE
}
```

> Cuando consulto por id en mi endpoint de PersonaController

```
...
    @GetMapping("persona/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Persona> getById(@PathVariable long id) {
           Persona user = service.findById(id);
            if (user!=null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                throw new PersonaNotFound("no encontrado");
            }
        }
    ...
```

> Cuando consulto el endpoint http://localhost:8082/api/persona/1 ,me arroja todo esto, y no tengo datos repetidos en la base de datos

```
{
"id": 1,
"nombre": "alejando ibarra sanchez",
"genero": "M",
"edad": 33,
"identificacion": "ife",
"direccion": "Barro Teran 123 Col Industrial,Cd Valles SLP",
"telefono": "563333",
"idcliente": 519,
"pass": "2345",
"estado": true,
"cuenta": [
{
"numerocuenta": 4,
"tipocuenta": "AHORRO",
"saldoinicial": 2000,
"statuscuenta": true,
"idCliente": {
"id": 1,
"nombre": "alejando ibarra sanchez",
"genero": "M",
"edad": 33,
"identificacion": "ife",
"direccion": "Barro Teran 123 Col Industrial,Cd Valles SLP",
"telefono": "563333",
"idcliente": 519,
"pass": "2345",
"estado": true,
"cuenta": [.....
```

> El metodo de guardar si funciona , pero no se porque me esta regresando todo esa informacion, no se si esta mal mapeado o que estoy haciendo mal. Alguna ayuda seria muy agradecida porque no se que mas hacerle.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mi problema es que estoy usando la estrategia herencia o joined para mis tablas una es persona y la otra cliente y esta ultima hereda atributos de persona, solo que quiero consultar por id de persona y no se si mapee mal las tablas , cliente tiene foreign key de persona y cuenta foreign key de cliente, espero se entienda